# Java ArrayList does not use overriden equals(Object o) method to compare

Tags: java, arraylist, equals

Why does ArrayList's contains(Object o) does not run my overridden equals(Object o) method? Consider this code:

```
private class TargetRC {
    public RComponent rc;

    public TargetRC(RComponent e) {
        rc = e;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof RComponent)
            return o == rc;
        else
            return o == this;
    }
}

private ArrayList<TargetRC> list = new ArrayList<TargetRC>();

public void add(RComponent e) {
    list.add(new TargetRC(e));
    System.out.println(list.contains(e));
}
```

As you see it is:

- Symetric because o == rc when and only when rc == o
- Reflexive because rc == rc

for any RComponent used in comparison.

Adding any element through visible here `add` method prints always false. No `println` works inside the `equals` method. Changing `==` operators to `equals` does not make any difference. What is wrong here?

Comment: Your `equals` is *not* symmetric, unless you're overriding `RComponent.equals()` to match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You test

```
list.contains(e)
```

with `e` being a `RComponent`.
So the list calls `RComponent.equals(Object)` for every element in your list
which always returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, only thing I had to do was to override ArrayList's indexOf method like this:

```
private ArrayList<TargetRC> list = new ArrayList<TargetRC>(){
    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o){
        for(int i=0; i<size(); ++i){
            if(get(i).equals(o)) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
```

Comment: Note that this is a significant code smell that can lead to trouble later.  Instead of making your `equals` method accept objects of a different type and have magical properties, write a `for` loop directly to compare the `rc` property to another `RComponent`.